# Statistical significance in mutations in two groups

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, genetics

I'm doing an analysis examining the mutations of a set of ~3 genes in 4 different populations. For Gene 1: In Group A 33/540 have that mutation, Group B 66/100, Group C 15/213, and Group D 20/32. And so on for each of the three genes. What is the appropriate statistical test to determine the pairwise differences in the groups mutation rates?

I am included to use R's chisq.test() assuming a chi-square test will work. However, I'm curious as to whether I'm missing something.

Comment: You have a binary variable, with multiple genes across several populations. You probably need something like `lme4::glmer(cbind(mutated, total) ~ Group + (Group | gene))`, although the random effect is hard to estimate for just three genes. (I've also voted to migrate.)

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told us, this sounds a lot like a heirarchical binomial model.

I'm going to assume that there is some population level mutation rate $\mu$.  Your sub-populations are thus samples from this larger population.  Each group will have a slightly different mutation rate $\theta_i$, but the expectation of the $\theta_i$ should be $\mu$.

Here is my stan model:

```
data{
 int num_groups;
 int y[num_groups];
 int N[num_groups];
}
parameters{

  real<lower=0, upper=1> mu;
  real<lower=0> kappa;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> theta[num_groups];
}
model{
 theta ~ beta(mu*kappa,(1-mu)*kappa);
 y~binomial(N,theta);
}
```

And here is my sampling call

```
library(rstan)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())

y = c(33,66,15,20)
N = c(540,100,213,32)
num_groups = length(N)
d = list(y = y, N = N, num_groups = num_groups)

fit = sampling(model, 
               data = d)

bayesplot::mcmc_areas(as.matrix(fit), regex_pars = 'theta', prob = 0.8, prob_outer = 0.95)
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]

From this plot, we can tell that populations A and C are quite similar and populations B and D are quite similar (though we should be careful since there is still a lot of posterior variance).

Overall, we estimate a 71% probability that the $\theta_D < \theta_B$, but again we can't say for sure because there is a ton of posterior variance.  One this is for sure, populations A and C are different than B and D.